# DoDirectPayment did not return response if payment successful

Tags: php, cakephp, paypal, cakephp-2.0

I am using `Paypal` `DoDirectPayment` (sandbox) in my web app . 
when i input wrong credit card info that time API return ACK status and also response body .

- response at failure time *

  ```
  Array
  (
      [TIMESTAMP] => 2014-02-27T08:41:33Z
      [CORRELATIONID] => sdsfsd3534
      [ACK] => Failure
      [VERSION] => 100.000
      [BUILD] => 5645654
      [L_ERRORCODE0] => 10002
      [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Security error
      [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => Security header is not valid
      [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error
      [ERRORS] => Array
          (
             error array
          )

  [REQUESTDATA] => Array
      (
          /* REQUEST DATA details */     
      )

  [RAWREQUEST] => /* RAWREQUEST */
  [RAWRESPONSE] => TIMESTAMP=2014%2d02%2d27T08%3a41%3a33Z&CORRELATIONID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXX&ACK=Failure&VERSION=XXXXXXX&BUILD=XXXXXXXX&L_ERRORCODE0=10002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Security%20error&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Security%20header%20is%20not%20valid&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
  ```

  )

but when payment successful

```
Array
(
    [ERRORS] => Array
        (
              empty 

        )

    [REQUESTDATA] => Array
        (
          /* REQUEST DATA details */           
         )

    [RAWREQUEST] => ' ..... '
    [RAWRESPONSE] => ?????? /* empty/blank  */
)
```

What was the issue with it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the same issue, but Paypal sandbox sometimes work, sometimes doesn't. I get a lot of empty responses on sandbox, or internal errors. This is not happening on live.

So most of that strange cases you can just treat as sandbox errors.